# Getting warning :SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED

Tags: ssis

I'm a beginner with SSIS. When I executed a package from SSIS, I got the warning: `SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED. The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (3) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors`.

Then I tried to update `MaximumErrorCount` to 4, but I got the warning again.

I'm using a flat-file source which has filespaths, then I'm using import column transformation where i configured everything like this:

1. Input column:-selected input column
2. Input and Output Properties:-configured both import column Input and import column Output and configured LineageID

Comment: How are you executing the package? Visual Studio, Execute Package Utiltity, SQL Server Agent Job?

Comment: Executing in Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

what is output column data type
it only works if datatype is one of DT_TEXT, DT_NTEXT, or DT_IMAGE